# Pass urls iteratively into django html template url tag

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a home template with links to many other pages which I want to render iteratively: (this obviously does not work due to python syntax)

```html
{% for idx, category in enumerate(categories) %}
    <div class="box">
        a href={% url 'category_links[idx]' %}> {{category}}</a>
    div>
{% endfor %}
```

I have the following urls which I also pass to my template from my view:

```py
category_links = ['journals', 'proceedings', 'books', 'articles_in_books', 'talks', 'poster', 'habilitations', 'phd_thesis', 'bachelor_master_diploma_thesis', 'lectures', 'conferences', 'calls_and_awards', 'telegrams_and_circulars']
```

I am aware of `{{forloop.counter0}}` but was unable to integrate it properly.

I would greatly appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0):

**You can loop trough list with {{ forloop.counter }} by simply make a custom template filter**

**I.E :** same as use `list_object[index]` in python

*templatetags/index.py* (create a templatetags folder in the app root directory)

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def index(list_object, i):
    return list_object[i]
```

*template.html*

```
{% load index %}

{% for category in categories %}
{% with forloop.counter0 as i %}
<div class="box">
    a href='{% url category_links|index:i %}'> {{category}}</a>
<div>
{% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I did that but now I get the error "NoReverseMatch at /
'category_links|index' is not a registered namespace"

Comment: I worked it out. The quotes have to be outside the tag like this ```<a href="{% url category_links|index:i %}" ```